# What hook to use to capture using switching to running application

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

Setting: Windows 8 Store App written in C#
I tried OnLaunched and OnActivated but neither seems to be called when the user switches away from the app and switches back.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 8 Store App paradigm for this is *suspending* and *resuming* (reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh770837.aspx)).

If you need to perform some operation when the user suspends or resumes, attach an event handler, like so:

```
Application.Current.Suspending += new SuspendingEventHandler(App_Suspending);
```

and:

```
async void App_Suspending(Object sender, 
    Windows.ApplicationModel.SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
    // some code here...
}
```

Resuming is handled in a similar manner.

Bear in mind that suspending doesn't happen instantaneously - it may take a couple seconds after the user has switched away for the event to be fired.

Comment: very often the app doesn't suspend even after the device goes into sleep mode... for many hours. i have an app that has content that changes every day. if the users switches apps and switches back after the content has changed i need to do a refresh. is there any hook that tells me that the users has just put the focus on my app beyond "resume"?

Comment: If your suspend/resume event handlers aren't getting called, something's going wrong... the VS debugger disables them - I assume you're not running in debug mode under VS?  Have you tried [manually triggering a resume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974425.aspx) within the debugger - does your resume event handler get called?

Comment: yeah, if i manually trigger it it's fine. my client tested whether the daily content refreshes by: 1) starting the app 2) going to the home screen 3) leaving the device overnight 4) starting the app again. it seems that it doesn't suspend even when the device goes into sleep mode!

Comment: Have you tried handling the [VisibilityChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.visibilitychanged.aspx) event instead?